# Game of Life with OpenMP

Tags: c, optimization, openmp, conways-game-of-life

I did a sequential version of game of life, but now I need to make a parallel version of my code using OpenMP, but I am having some issues with it.
If anyone could help me, it would be very nice. Thks.
Here's my sequential code:

```
// Swapping the two grids   
 #define SWAP_BOARDS( b1, b2 )  do { \
 char* temp = b1; \
 b1 = b2; \
 b2 = temp; \
 } while(0)

// Simplifying access to grid elements
   #define BOARD( G, X, Y )  ((G)[NC*(X)+(Y)])

 char* sequential_game_of_life (char* outgrid, char* ingrid, 
       const int nrows, const int ncols, const int gens_max) {

  const int NC = ncols;
  int curgen, i, j;

 for (curgen = 0; curgen < gens_max; curgen++)
   {

  for (i = 0; i < nrows; i++)
{
  for (j = 0; j < ncols; j++)
    {
      const int inorth = mod (i-1, nrows);
      const int isouth = mod (i+1, nrows);
      const int jwest = mod (j-1, ncols);
      const int jeast = mod (j+1, ncols);

      const char neighbor_count = 
    BOARD (ingrid, inorth, jwest) + 
    BOARD (ingrid, inorth, j) + 
    BOARD (ingrid, inorth, jeast) + 
    BOARD (ingrid, i, jwest) +
    BOARD (ingrid, i, jeast) + 
    BOARD (ingrid, isouth, jwest) +
    BOARD (ingrid, isouth, j) + 
    BOARD (ingrid, isouth, jeast);

      BOARD(outgrid, i, j) = alivep (neighbor_count, BOARD (ingrid, i, j));
    }
}
  SWAP_BOARDS( outgrid, ingrid );
}
  return outgrid;
 }
```

I know that I have to parallel those 3 for's, but I cant see how to do that.

Comment: So what's the question? Is it something like "How can I make the 3 `for` loops run in parallel with OpenMP?" or something like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the outer loop can not be parallelized, because input to each generation is the previous generation, so it has a sequential formula (at least you can not do it with minor changes!)

In case of nested loops which traverse a matrix or something like that, I prefer to run a single loop from `0` to `ncol*nrow` (in your case) and find `i` and `j` from loop index.

like this:

```
// because you are running a parallel codes multiple times in a loop,
// it would be better to make the thread swarm first and schedule the
// tasks in each loop iteration, to avoid multiple creation and destruction
// of working threads
#pragma omp parallel
for (curgen = 0; curgen < gens_max; curgen++)
{
    #pragma omp for
    for (t = 0; t < nrows*ncols; t++)
    {
        int i = t / ncols;
        int j = t % ncols;
        const int inorth = mod (i-1, nrows);
        const int isouth = mod (i+1, nrows);
        const int jwest = mod (j-1, ncols);
        const int jeast = mod (j+1, ncols);

        const char neighbor_count = 
            BOARD (ingrid, inorth, jwest) + 
            BOARD (ingrid, inorth, j) + 
            BOARD (ingrid, inorth, jeast) + 
            BOARD (ingrid, i, jwest) +
            BOARD (ingrid, i, jeast) + 
            BOARD (ingrid, isouth, jwest) +
            BOARD (ingrid, isouth, j) + 
            BOARD (ingrid, isouth, jeast);

        BOARD(outgrid, i, j) = alivep (neighbor_count, BOARD (ingrid, i, j));
    }
    SWAP_BOARDS( outgrid, ingrid );
}
```

I ran this code on my laptop with Dual Core 2.53 GHz CPU on a 1000x1000 matrix over 1000 generations, and got 69% speed up.

Comment: Very good, but I have some doubts here, actually two:
first: Shouldnt I have to define a parallel region with something like  #pragma omp parallel num_threads(NTHREADS) private(t) ?

Second: When I run the algorithm with your advice it is faster using just 1 thread than using 4. Any guess why that is happening?

Comment: `#pragma omp parallel for` is a shortcut for `#pragma omp parallel` and then `#pragma omp for`. You can specify other options in it too, like: `#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(N)`. For the speed up, please check the updated answer

Comment: You must give `curgen` the private treatment. Manual loops collapsing is redundant when there is the `collapse(n)` OpenMP directive.

Comment: Very good explanation saeedn, actually I've been running this code with 6x5 matrix and 2048 generations, so the problem may be the size of my matrix, since its too small I couldnt see any speedup. And for curiosity how many threads are you running? Since its a dual core after 4 threads, the performance may not be too good right?

Comment: @tsukanomon I used the default number of threads, which is equal to number of cores (2 in my case)

Comment: @saeedn Thank you very much for your help, it was very useful and clear.