# Issues from using code from a previous code here on Stackoverflow.com - Game of life in C with OpenMp

Tags: c, openmp

I tried to replicate the code in this post in my visual studio IDE and I got some errors even though I didn't change any part of the code. The code is from this post - [Game of Life with OpenMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13846477/game-of-life-with-openmp)

This is the code from the post -

```
// Swapping the two grids   
 #define SWAP_BOARDS( b1, b2 )  do { \
 char* temp = b1; \
 b1 = b2; \
 b2 = temp; \
 } while(0)

// Simplifying access to grid elements
   #define BOARD( G, X, Y )  ((G)[NC*(X)+(Y)])

 char* sequential_game_of_life (char* outgrid, char* ingrid, 
       const int nrows, const int ncols, const int gens_max) {

  const int NC = ncols;
  int curgen, i, j;

 for (curgen = 0; curgen < gens_max; curgen++)
   {

  for (i = 0; i < nrows; i++)
{
  for (j = 0; j < ncols; j++)
    {
      const int inorth = mod (i-1, nrows);
      const int isouth = mod (i+1, nrows);
      const int jwest = mod (j-1, ncols);
      const int jeast = mod (j+1, ncols);

      const char neighbor_count = 
    BOARD (ingrid, inorth, jwest) + 
    BOARD (ingrid, inorth, j) + 
    BOARD (ingrid, inorth, jeast) + 
    BOARD (ingrid, i, jwest) +
    BOARD (ingrid, i, jeast) + 
    BOARD (ingrid, isouth, jwest) +
    BOARD (ingrid, isouth, j) + 
    BOARD (ingrid, isouth, jeast);

      BOARD(outgrid, i, j) = alivep (neighbor_count, BOARD (ingrid, i, j));
    }
}
  SWAP_BOARDS( outgrid, ingrid );
}
  return outgrid;
 }
```

I'm getting the errors below -

```
Errors 
     char* temp = b1 `--> expression must have a constant value`
     b1 = b2;    --> `expression must have a constant value`
     b2 = temp;  --> `expression must have a constant value`
```

Also the last line of the code is showing an error as an
"unrecognized token":

```
SWAP_BOARDS( outgrid, ingrid ); --> `unrecognized token`
```

Please how do I resolve these issues? Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: The provided code builds on GCC 11.2, Clang 13 and MSVC 19 without adding any additional flags/options. Please give the build command or at least more information.

Comment: How do you call 'sequential_game_of_life' function?

Comment: @Laci, 'sequential_game_of_life' function wasn't called in the post, it was just declared and I also just did the same thing. Thanks.

Comment: @JérômeRichard, I have GCC 11.2, MSVC 2022, I'm using a windows 8.1, I don't have Clang. Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us the whole gcc output/error message? How do you define `mod` and `alivep` functions?

Comment: @Laci, I had a little typo in my code but I've corrected that now. The whole gcc output/error list message is too long to fit into one comment here on stackoverflow so, I'll add it as multiple comments. Output - Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: GameOfLife_Serialized, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>Game_of_Life.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol mod referenced in function sequential_game_of_life
1>Game_of_Life.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol alivep referenced in function sequential_game_of_life

Comment: @Laci, Remaining Output - 1>MSVCRTD.lib(exe_main.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol main referenced in function "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ)
1>C:\Users\Babatunde\source\repos\GameOfLife_Serialized\x64\Debug\GameOfLife_Serialized.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals
1>Done building project "GameOfLife_Serialized.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: @Laci, The typo must have affected the previous outputs but what I sent above (the last 2 comments) are the output/error message, thanks a lot.

Comment: It seems that you can compile the code, but it not surprising that you cannot link it, because the missing `main`, `mod` and `alivep` functions.

Comment: @Laci, please how do I create the mod and alivep functions ? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, I answer your question in comments. The board of the [Game of Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life) should be an infinite, two-dimensional orthogonal grid of square cells. Infinity can be 'approximated' by connecting the edges of the board. To do it the `mod` function should be defined as a modulo function.

```
int mod(int x, int y){return x%y;}
```

The [rules of game of life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life) are:

1. Any live cell with two or three live neighbours survives.
2. Any dead cell with three live neighbours becomes a live cell.
3. All other live cells die in the next generation. Similarly, all other dead cells stay dead.

The function `alivep` is the definition of the above mentioned rules. There are 2 input parameters: the number of living neighbours and the state of cell (alive or dead). The return value is the state of cell in the next cycle. Assuming `0` means dead, `1` means alive, here is an example how to implement it:

```
char alivep(int neighbours, char alive){
    if (alive && (neighbours==2 || neighbours==3)) return 1; 
    else { 
        if (neighbours==3) return 1; else return 0;
    }
}
```

Putting it together, defining the `main` function, adding a `print_board` function to show the board, here is an example to do it:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int mod(int x, int y){return x%y;}

char alivep(int neighbours, char alive){
    if (alive && (neighbours==2 || neighbours==3)) return 1; 
    else { 
        if (neighbours==3) return 1; else return 0;
    }
}

// Swapping the two grids   
 #define SWAP_BOARDS( b1, b2 ) { \
 char* temp = b1; \
 b1 = b2; \
 b2 = temp; \
 }

// Simplifying access to grid elements
#define BOARD( G, X, Y )  ((G)[ncols*(X)+(Y)])

char* sequential_game_of_life (char* outgrid, char* ingrid, 
       const int nrows, const int ncols, const int gens_max) {

 for (int curgen = 0; curgen < gens_max; curgen++){
    for (int i = 0; i < nrows; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < ncols; j++){
            const int inorth = mod (i-1, nrows);
            const int isouth = mod (i+1, nrows);
            const int jwest = mod (j-1, ncols);
            const int jeast = mod (j+1, ncols);

            const char neighbor_count = 
            BOARD (ingrid, inorth, jwest) + 
            BOARD (ingrid, inorth, j) + 
            BOARD (ingrid, inorth, jeast) + 
            BOARD (ingrid, i, jwest) +
            BOARD (ingrid, i, jeast) + 
            BOARD (ingrid, isouth, jwest) +
            BOARD (ingrid, isouth, j) + 
            BOARD (ingrid, isouth, jeast);

            BOARD(outgrid, i, j) = alivep (neighbor_count, BOARD (ingrid, i, j));
        }
    }
    SWAP_BOARDS( outgrid, ingrid );
 }
 return outgrid;
}

void print_board(char* ingrid, int nrows, int ncols)
{
    for(int i=0;i<nrows;++i)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<ncols;++j)
        {
            printf("%c", BOARD(ingrid,i,j)==0 ? '.' : '*');            
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}


int main(){
    const int NR=15;
    const int NC=15;
    const int GENS_MAX=20;

    char ingrid[NR*NC];
    char outgrid[NR*NC];
    memset(ingrid,0,NR*NC*sizeof(ingrid[0]));
    
    //draw an example pattern
    ingrid[5*NC+5]=1;
    ingrid[5*NC+6]=1;
    ingrid[5*NC+7]=1;
    ingrid[5*NC+8]=1;
    ingrid[6*NC+5]=1;
    ingrid[7*NC+5]=1;
    ingrid[8*NC+5]=1;
    ingrid[9*NC+5]=1;

    printf("Initial board\n");
    print_board(ingrid, NR, NC);

    char* out=sequential_game_of_life (outgrid, ingrid, NR, NC, GENS_MAX);
    
    printf("Final board\n");
    print_board(out, NR, NC);
}
```

Comment: thank you so much, I'm really grateful for your help.

Comment: There seems to be an issue with my MVS 2022, It's showing an error that NC in the main is "undefined" but I can see that its defined in the main as --> const int NC = 15; and it's also showing an error that "the expression must have a constant value" which it already does. Any ideal what could be wrong please?

Comment: I have changed the `BOARD` macro, please check if you use `#define BOARD( G, X, Y )  ((G)[ncols*(X)+(Y)])` line.

Comment: It worked for NC in the main, it's no longer showing as "undefined" but these two are still showing an error that NR and NC in (char ingrid[NR * NC]; char outgrid[NR * NC];) --> "expression must have a constant value" which I can see they already have in the main. Please how do I resolve this issue ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you used `const int NR=15; const int NC=15;`?

Comment: Yes, that's what I used.

Comment: If you use a C++ compiler use `constexpr` instead of `const`, in the case of C compiler use `#define NR 15` and `#define NC 15`.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot.