# Using OpenMP leads to slow execution and wrong results

Tags: c++, openmp

I implemented a version of Game of Life for a university course and I would like to speed up the code using OpenMP.

The problems I am running into are:

- Execution time slower than sequentially
- The result of gol after 250 generations is wrong

you can find the sequential code [in my github](https://github.com/Raavgo/Game-of-Life/tree/master)

I have tried several different approaches already and currently this is my latest try:

```
std::vector<std::vector<char>> computation_board = board;

bool cellAlive;
//Sequential speed = 0:00.010;0:27.634;0:00.085
int i, m, n, alive;

for (i = 0; i < generations; i++){
    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(2) default(none) shared(computation_board, alive, cellAlive)  reduction(+: n, m)
    #pragma omp for  collapse(2) schedule(auto)
    for (m= 0; m <= height; m++){
        for(n=0; n<= width; n++){
            alive = getAliveNeighbours(m, n);
            cellAlive = board[m][n] == 'x';
            char result;

            //If cell is dead
            if(!cellAlive){
                //Rule 1
                if(alive == 3){
                    result = 'x';
                }else{
                    result = '.';
                }
            }

            //If cell is alive
            if(cellAlive){
                //Rule 2
                if(alive == 2 || alive == 3){
                    result = 'x';
                }else
                    //Rule 3 and 4
                    if(alive < 2 || alive > 3){
                    result = '.';
                }
            }

            computation_board[m][n] = result;
        }
    }

    //After all cells where visited store the computation_board as the new board
    #pragma omp barrier
    board = computation_board;
}
```

It is 3x slower and outputs the wrong values.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have data race in your code (please use your variables in their minimum required scope), `reduction` and `barrier` is not needed at all.  How big is `height` and `width`?

Comment: You declare for instance `alive` as shared. Why? That means that all threads are using the same location in memory to update this value. Instead they all need to have their own private instance. As @Laci remarks: declaring such variables local would instantly solve the problem.

Comment: If performance is critical my suggestion is to first tune your serial code, it can be significantly improved and you may not need any parallelization. E.g. do not use vector of vectors, and you do not need to copy the board (it is very expensive, swapping its pointers is much faster), etc. I think you can easily find very fast implementations, but if it is your homework it is a different story...

Comment: @Laci height and width can depend on the input file.  The smallest file ich have is w=1000, h =250 and the biggest is w=1000, h=2000.
And yes it is part of the assignment to use openmp but I am also pretty invested right now. I already tried removing the vector of vector and it did not improve very much. It was like 5s faster but then I realized the output is wrong so I changed it back to the original code because I thought I broke the code.

Comment: Please check the code in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70547302/issues-from-using-code-from-a-previous-code-here-on-stackoverflow-com-game-of/70576389#70576389

Comment: @Laci So you think I can't parallelize my code? Not that I am not thankful for the solution but I worked really hard on my code and did not look at solutions and tried it on my own and now I kinda want to see it through, Even though my code is not optimal.

Comment: try `#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(2) default(none) shared(computation_board, board), private(alive, cellAlive, n, m)` and delete `#pragma omp for  collapse(2) schedule(auto)` and `#pragma omp barrier`. I think the result should be correct.

Comment: @Laci It didn't work out of the box but after recoding the loop and reducing it to one loop it worked like a charm, somehow omp doesn't like nested loops. But thanks, your comment helped a lot.